# Updating the DOM with change in an object (vue.js) - binding not working?

Tags: ajax, dom, vue.js

I have the **app.js** file where gmarkers is an array of objects :

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#lili',
    data: {
        listings: gmarkers
    }
});
```

In my **HTML** file :

```
<div id="lili" >
    <div
        v-repeat="gmarker : listings" 
        class="listing listing-list col-sm-12" 
        style="height:50px;line-height:50px;"  
        data-cat="@{{gmarker.mycategory}}" 
        data-id="@{{gmarker.id}}"
    >
        <span style="color:black;">
            <a target="_blank" href="@{{gmarker.listlink}}">
                @{{ gmarker.listname }}
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="tag blue-back" style="margin-left:5px;">
            <a target="_blank" href="@{{gmarker.catlink}}">
                @{{gmarker.listcat}}
            </a>
        </span>
        <span style="margin-left:20px;color:#bbb;">
            @{{gmarker.distance}}km
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When loading the page, the DOM loads correctly, displaying the list I'm looking for but when (after an ajax call in js) the gmarkers object changes, the DOM doesn't change.
The new gmarkers is totally created from scratch and containing new objects.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sound like you are wrong about what data is being bound here. You are expecting `data: {listings: gmarkers}` to do binding between `vm.listings` and the `gmarkers` array. This isn't what it does. It copies the gmarkers data into the listings and doesn't listen to gmarkers anymore. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j8czvLb/) for an example of what I think you are doing wrong.

We can fix the above fiddle by setting the vm.listings to the new array of objects after the ajax request.

```
vm.$set('listings', gmarkers);
```

You can see this in action in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j8czvLb/1/).

It is actually pretty common to see a blank listings until ajax returns them. Here is some sample code that will call an ajax request when vue is ready and update the listings once it is finished. **Note:** this exampe uses [vue-resources](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) to perform the ajax request. You may not have this. You can always just use jQuery or javascript to perform this.

```
data: {
    listings: []
},
ready: function () {
  this.fetchListings();
},
methods: {
  fetchListings: function () {
    this.$http.get('/your/api/listings', function (response) {
      this.$set('listings', response);
    });
  }
}
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j8czvLb/2/) shows the above code but pay attention to the differences required for the fake ajax request I used.

Comment: I created a fiddle for you. To make questions easier to understand and answer I'd suggest creating a fiddle when possible.

Comment: Man, you made my day and my weekend ! Thank you for all the info. It was indeed that the problem and solution.